# Node.js socket io multiple timer for rooms

Tags: node.js, sockets, timer

Which solution is the best for multiple rooms timer?

In every room will be a timer, which will send every second actual time every client in rooms.

But I think this solution will be very risky, can slow down the server or kill it. Because when will be 500 clients, it will send very second 500 packets and its huge count.

Is there any async timer?

This is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
    if (rooms) {
        for (var roomKey in rooms) {
            var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomKey];
            if (typeof room.time !== 'undefined') {
                if (room.time <= 0) {
                    room.time = 60;
                    // emit time up
                } else {
                    room.time--;
                    // emit time
                }
                console.log(room);
            }
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If you think 500 clients is huge, you should see an enterprise application that supports 500,000+

Comment: Is possible handle 500 clients with this code ? (With one server)